# Scikit: Use LabelBinarizer in Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In my dataset, i have one string column that I'm transforming using a LabelBinarizer in order to run a classifier. The string column has about 5 values that I'm transforming. I'm able to successfully build a model but the issue is the prediction input needs to be passed in as binaryFormat like this:

> forest.predict([[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]]).

I am looking for a way to use the raw attribute value and the transformer converts it on the fly. Something like this

> forest.predict([[0,0,1,1,1,'A']]).

Can this be accomplished using a pipeline? If so, I would really appreciate some links or samples to work off?

Code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/pydata/test.csv') #has attrs v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,class
binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
labeled_dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame( binarizer.fit_transform(data["v5"]), columns=binarizer.classes_)

X = data.drop(columns=["v5","class"]).join(labeled_dataframe1).as_matrix()
y = data['class'].as_matrix()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)

# Model fitting
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500)
forest.fit(X_train,y_train)

# Predict
forest.predict([[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

Comment: What happens when some data is present in test and not in train. LabelBinarizer will throw error there. Its better to convert whole data using the binarizer and then split into train test.

Comment: It is guaranteed that all possible values would be covered during training so that situation wouldnt arise.